# Add a lightning component in record Page Community

Tags: page-layout, community-builder

I want to add a lightning component in the layout of a record page of a community. Inside salesforce i have clicked edit page, and added the component. But i also want to expose it somehow in my community but it does not appear. Any ideas ?

Comment: add `forceCommunity:availableForAllPageTypes` interface

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should add interface or target symbol before you add any lightning component to Community page via Community Builder.

If you use **Lightning Aura Component** i.e. `aura`, add`forceCommunity:availableForAllPageTypes`:

```html
<aura:component implements="forceCommunity:availableForAllPageTypes">
<!-- code -->
</aura:component>
```

If you use **Lightning Web Component** i.e. `lwc`, add`<target>lightningCommunity__Page</target>` to Component Configuration File:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<LightningComponentBundle xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
    <apiVersion>47.0</apiVersion>
    <isExposed>true</isExposed>
    <targets>
        <target>lightning__RecordPage</target>
        <target>lightningCommunity__Page</target>
    </targets>
</LightningComponentBundle>
```

Friendly you can find more related information from Salesforce reference from [aura](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/forceCommunity:availableForAllPageTypes/documentation) or [lwc](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/en/lwc/lwc.use_config_for_community_builder)

Comment: Thanks for the solution!!

Comment: Lol, he copied and improve it, booooh!

Comment: @Pirata21 I've worked on this part recently and also developed related code in a Salesforce IDE. Your answer includes the core of the solution but not is not friendly to anyone not familiar with Lightning. I cannot comment on your answer so I decide to write a more friendly version. Thanks for your support to the community.

Answer (score 1):

You must have to specify it, on the metadata:

**LWC**:
`

```
<isExposed>true</isExposed>
 <targets>
    <target> lightning__RecordPage </target>
 </targets>`
```

**Aura**:

```
<aura:component implements="flexipage:availableForRecordHome" access="global">
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution!!